# NearestNeighborGraph doesn't show a 3D graph when one or more points are Integer and the rest are Decimal?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.3 or earlier and fixed in 13.1**

---

When all the points are the same kind, say `Integer` then `NearestNeighborGraph` will display a 3D graph when using `{x,y,z}` coordinates.  However, when just one of those points is say a `Decimal` instead then one sees a 2D graph. It seems the reverse is true too. For example:

```
allIntegers = NearestNeighborGraph[{{0,0,0},{-1,1,1},{1,-1,1},{-1,-1,1},{1,1,1},{0,0,2},{0,0,1}},{All,2}];
allDecimals = NearestNeighborGraph[{{0.,0.,0.},{-1.,1.,1.},{1.,-1.,1.},{-1.,-1.,1.},{1.,1.,1.},{0.,0.,2.},{0.,0.,1.}},{All,2}];

oneInteger = NearestNeighborGraph[{{0,0.,0.},{-1.,1.,1.},{1.,-1.,1.},{-1.,-1.,1.},{1.,1.,1.},{0.,0.,2.},{0.,0.,1.}},{All,2}];
oneDecimal = NearestNeighborGraph[{{0.,0,0},{-1,1,1},{1,-1,1},{-1,-1,1},{1,1,1},{0,0,2},{0,0,1}},{All,2}];

Row[{allIntegers, allDecimals, oneInteger, oneDecimal}]
```

Displays:

[image: 2 3D graphs and 2 2D graphs]

Is there something I'm doing wrong or some parameter I need to pass?  I'd like to be able to force 3D.

Comment: I would call this a bug. Please report it to Wolfram. Note that this is not an official Wolfram website, so the issue won't come to their attention unless you report it.

Comment: Bug reported, lets see what happens.

Comment: I received an email on the 13th of September 2022 to say it's now been fixed. I've tested it in 13.1 and all test cases above return 3D Graphs as expected.

Comment: In similar cases, feel free to edit the bug header. I'll do it this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible workaround to this bug is to set [`VertexCoordinates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html) explicitly.

```
pts = {{0., 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 1}};

NearestNeighborGraph[pts, {All, 2}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> pts (* <-- workaround *)]
```